# How to access static block variables outside of class in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, static-block

I was working on some code in which I need to access the variable "hs" present in the static block of one class from another.
Note: Both the class are preset in different packages.

Code is as follow:

```
public class A{
    static {
        HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

I Googled about it but nothing found anything helpful.
Your help would be very appreciable.

EDIT: I am not allowed to make changes in this file still need to access it from the other file.

Why I need to do this cause I am doing unit testing by JUnit and there is nothing what this block is returning which I can put assertEquals() on. So the option I left with is to test the side-effects and this variable "hs" value is getting changed as a side-effect. That's why I need to access it from another file.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Thanks for the quick reply. Actually the work is something like that I can't make changes in the code, and still need to access it from the another file. Can you help me with it.

Comment: There is no way for you to access this variable. It only exists temporary during the static block and has nothing to do with the class `A`.

Comment: This might be an [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you can add an explanation why you even wan't do that?

Comment: @lealceldeiro No it isn't. No access modifier is associated with a local variable.

Comment: @second I have edited the explanation, check if it clarifies that why i need to do this.

Comment: In unit tests you are supposed to test `public methods` and `object states` not local variables. `hs` is not a `side-effect` unless it is assigned to another variable that has something to do with the class `A`. Maybe you want to add what else the static block is doing.

Comment: If you can't change this code your question embodies a contradiction in terms. And as you agree that 'there is nothing what this block is returning', there is nothing here that needs testing.

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as `public static` inside the class and initialize it in static block

```
class A1{
public static HashSet<String> hs;
static {
     hs= new HashSet<>();
    }
 }
```

Comment: The TO wrote he can not change the code, so that is not really an option.

Comment: There nothing he can do without changing code @second

Answer (score 1):

Need create getter and setter for variable "hs".

Class 1:

```
public class Test {

    public static HashSet<String> hs;

    static {
        hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.add("Test14");
        hs.add("Test15");
        hs.add("Test16");
    }

    public static HashSet<String> getHs() {
        return hs;
    }

    public static void setHs(HashSet<String> hs) {
        Test.hs = hs;
    }


}
```

Class 2

If you need to use "hs" variable in without static method then:

```
public class Test2 {

    public void test() {
        Test ts = new Test();
        ts.getHs();
    }
}
```

If you need to use "hs" variable in with static method then:

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void test() {
        Test.getHs();
    }
}
```